# How do I deal with promises in setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react code, that represents a text input.

```
 onChangeDestination(url, index) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const rules = [...prevState.rules];
      rules[index] = { ...rules[index], url};
      if (isURL(url+'')) {
        testURL(url).then(r=> {
          var url_status = r.data.response
          rules[index] = { ...rules[index], url_status};
        })
      } else {
         var url_status = "No URL"
         rules[index] = { ...rules[index], url_status};
      }
      return { rules };
    });
  };
```

In English:

If the URL passes `isURL()` validation, then use custom function `testURL()` to see what the HTTP status of that URL is (using `axios`).

In my template, there's a {props.url_status} for the relevant bit.

The issue is, even though it's logging to the console the desired behaviour, it doesn't seem to be updating the viewport reliably, which I think is linked to the promise.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The easiest solution is to resolve the promise first and then set the state, otherwise your state update will resolve before the promise does.

Comment: How do I do that? That's the issue I've been having, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to block

Comment: You don't need to block it, you can do `testURL(...).then(() => this.setState(...))`. As a general tip, Javascript is single threaded (aside from web workers), so you never want to block anything or otherwise the page will hang until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by converting your function to be asynchronous and calling your promise (if necessary)  before your `setState`. This solution uses the easier to read `async/await` syntax and a ternary condition to choose the correct status value :

```
const url_status = isURL(url + '') ? (await testURL(url)).data.response : "No URL"
```

This line will execute your promise and wait for it only if `isURL` return `true`, if so it will return the response part and if not, it will send out `"No URL"`.

Full code :

```
async onChangeDestination(url, index) {
    const url_status = isURL(url + '') ? (await testURL(url)).data.response : "No URL"
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const rules = [...prevState.rules];
        rules[index] = { 
            ...rules[index],
            url,
            url_status
        };
        return { rules };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use more components with some particular single task only. In this case: you might need a stateless Input component with an `onChange` and a `value` prop. Its parent could be some container where the `onChange` triggers some async request and has a state like `url_status`. As @Nit commented set the state in the promise `then` clause. This `url_status` will be a prop of some other component, so in case of the prop changes that component will re-render automatically... In most of the cases you do not need to use states at all.